# Match a single character in a Bash regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, shell

For some reason, the following regular expression match doesn't seem to be working.

```
string="#Hello world";
[[ "$string" =~ 'ello' ]] && echo "matches";
[[ "$string" =~ 'el.o' ]] && echo "matches";
```

The first command succeeds (as expected), but the second one does not.

Shouldn't that period be treated by the regular expression as a single character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the period causes it to be treated as a literal character, not a regular-expression metacharacter. Best practice if you want to quote the entire regular expression is to do so in a variable, where regular expression matching rules aren't in effect, then expand the parameter unquoted (which is safe to do inside `[[ ... ]]`).

```
regex='el.o'
[[ "$string" =~ $regex ]] && echo "matches"
```

Comment: So, I'm guessing that means `[[` isn't just an alias for a command, and there is some magic mojo going on behind the scenes, right?

Comment: Correct; `[` is an alias for `test`, but `[[` is a (nonalphabetic) keyword that introduces one of `bash`'s compound commands. It has its own rules for evaluating the expressions contained within.

Comment: Is there a name for the `[[` keyword? I'm having a tough time knowing what to Google for in order to read more about it.

Comment: I'm not aware of any commonly used term, but no need to google: It's all in the man-page.

Answer (score 0):

```
string="#Hello world";
[[ "$string" =~ ello ]] && echo "matches";
[[ "$string" =~ el.o ]] && echo "matches";
```

Test

```
$ string="hh elxo fj"
$ [[ "$string" =~ el.o ]] && echo "matches";
matches
```